# Get info about worker crash

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using this code to handle cluster crashes in my node application

```
cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
  console.log("error in cluster",worker);
  console.log("cluster code",code);
  console.log("cluster signal",signal);
  const newFork = cluster.fork();
});
```

I am trying to get the reason for the worker going down but the data inside worker, code and signal parameters did not have any details about the error from what I could see. Is there any way to find what the reason for the crash is?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `error` event to get the error inside your fork.

```js
const worker = cluster.fork();

worker.on("error", function(data) {
    constole.log("error in cluster", data);
})
```

Comment: Tired this out but I get the same error message that I get from cluster.on('exit' . This does not seem to have the cause of the error.